# Rating an android app within an application

Tags: android, rating

I am trying to have the functionality where I can allow the users to rate my app from my application. I am not concentrating on the usual android market pointing and then doing it. Instead I want my application to have direct rating system.

I am pretty sure that this can be done i iPhone, but any one knows to do in android?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is how we can rate an app, the one suggested in the android official site.

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
  intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.test(This is the package name)"));
  startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: .I used this code its working but i want to show rating stars, is their any option to see direct rating stars ?

Answer (score 1):

An app can't rate itself, only the user can do so; this approach reduces abuse. 
Apps normally ask them to go to Android Market to rate them, as they reduce the abuse factor.
In one app, however, I've been told that I will get a bonus if I rate that app a certain way (for example, five stars).

Comment: Yeah I agree, we need to connect to android market. But I am pretty sure that there is tricky way for this, because in iPhone, people where I work, have done this.